# Adduser before usermod?

Tags: bash, shell, debian

This is a quick one that I cant figure out. Does usermod actually create a new user if the user specified doesn't already exist?

Here is an example:
    usermod -s /bin/false $1

If user "tom" doesn't exist already, will he be created, or would I need a command like "adduser" first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
# usermod -s /bin/false xyz
usermod: user 'xyz' does not exist
```

`man usermod` tells you that this is to modify user accounts, hence you'll need an existing one.

```
NAME
       usermod - modify a user account
```

If you like to create a user with some specific shell in one shot use -s switch with `useradd`:

```
# useradd -s /bin/false _username_
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to combine adding a new user and setting them to shell bin/false in a single command?

Comment: @JamesWillson: Try `man useradd`, note how similar it is to `man usermod`. :)

Comment: Should I be doing this? "useradd -s /bin/false tom"

Comment: @JamesWillson: That should work.

Comment: @JamesWillson: You can confirm the results by `grep tom /etc/passwd`